# Unrecognized token '<' when running hugging face transformers

Tags: reactjs, huggingface-transformers

I downloaded the react translation example. When I start the app everything seems to render fine, but as soon as I press translate, nothing happens and I get this error in the console on the browser:
`Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'`

I've gotten this same issue trying to run other models keeping things very basic as found here: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers.js/pipelines